# Solidity: Interface Usage

Tags: solidity

I have just starting learning Solidity but I am having a hard time in grasping the concept of Interfaces in Solidity. From what I understand It is a blueprint which the contracts have to follow with no implementation of the functions inside Interface.

Let's say the Interface is called AggregatorV3Interface and version is a function whose implementation have not been defined.

when I write AggregatorV3interface(addr).version(). in my solidity code why am I able to obtain the version of my address when the implementation of version function have not been defined. Moreover generally speaking whose address do we passed into our interface parameter?

Answer (score -1):

It's understandable that the concept of Interfaces in Solidity can be a bit challenging, especially when you're just starting out. Here's how they work:

Interfaces are indeed like blueprints or contracts that other contracts must follow. They define function signatures without providing the implementation. When you define an interface and then implement a contract that adheres to that interface, the implementing contract must provide the actual code for the functions defined in the interface.

Now, let's take a closer look at the AggregatorV3Interface(addr).version() example:

Interface Definition: The AggregatorV3Interface is defining a contract signature that includes a version function. The function itself doesn't do anything within the interface, but it says, "Any contract that wants to call itself an AggregatorV3Interface must have a function named version that looks like this."

Contract Implementation: Somewhere else in your code or in someone else's code, there will be a contract that implements AggregatorV3Interface. That contract will include the actual code for the version function, defining what it does and how it behaves and it will be deployed at some address.

Using the Interface: When you call AggregatorV3Interface(addr).version(), you are saying, "I'm going to take the contract at address addr, and I'm going to treat it as an AggregatorV3Interface, and then I'm going to call its version function." The address you pass in should be the address of a deployed contract that adheres to the AggregatorV3Interface definition.

You can also use the implementation to make the call using

```
AggregatorV3Interface(addr).version()
```

Its best practice to use the interface however it worth noting that if you use the interface to make the call you want have access to any of the state variables defined on the contract for example if you have defined on the implementation contract

```
unit256 public myNumber
```

you can access it using the implementation but not the interface

Calling the Actual Implementation: If the contract at that address does, in fact, adhere to the interface, then Solidity will call the actual version function defined in that contract, not the empty signature in the interface.